# Include view in my schema.xml

Tags: php, xml, view, propel

I need to do include my database's view in schema.xml.

1) i create a view in my SQL database
2) i launch this command (propel database:reverse) for generate a new schema.xml

Then i would like to do `propel model:build` for create view's model and doing query like this:

```
$collection = MyView::create()->find();
```

But when i create new schema.xml there are not any view, so i can not build view's model.

How can i include my view in schema.xml and then build their model?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a view similar to a table, then add the `skipSql` and `readOnly` attributes:

```
<table name='MyView' skipSQL='true' readOnly='true' ...
```